# Sudo error: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root? (sudo executable is already root/root 4755)

Tags: centos, sudo

Running `/usr/bin/env sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart` on a godaddy vps works fine from the shell.
The same command executed remotely via capistrano generates the following error:

`sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?`

File permissions on sudo executable are:

> File: ‘/usr/bin/sudo’ Size: 155008          Blocks: 304        IO
>   Block: 4096   regular file Device: fc00h/64512d    Inode: 914213
>   Links: 1 Access: (4755/-rwsr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (
>   0/    root)

Is there a way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is the problem specific to this command? Can you run other stuff through Capistrano?

Comment: @Paul Haldane All other commands run fine, just the sudo commands. I ran with --trace ... went through the logs searching for a clue I am at a loss to debug this.

Comment: The command works when executed as deploy user on remote server ... seems to only fail from remote shell.

Comment: @stefgosselin - did you ever get this resolved? I'm the same error when trying to sudo through another program. Same command works fine from shell.